# Plot horizontal lines in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am plotting horizontal lines but I am getting all in the same plot. I want a line per subplot. I tried using `ax` and I do get the subplots but all the lines are plotted in the last subplot.
What can I change?

Also, I want to assign a color to each integer of the random array. So when I plot the lines, I also see the different colors and not just the different lengths.

I already did this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3)
randnums= np.random.randint(0,10,9)
y= np.random.randint(1,10,9)
print(randnums)

plt.hlines(y=y, xmin=1, xmax=randnums)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want 1 line per subplot?

Comment: @user195366 In general, steer clear of the state-machine approach (`plt.method`) because it never does what you intend if you have more than one figure or ax. Typically the functions calls affect the last figure or ax you modified. `ax.method` is much clearer, as illustrated by the various answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what are you looking for, but if you need one random line per subplot, then you can do this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True)
line_lengths = np.random.randint(0, 10 ,9)
ys = np.random.randint(1, 10 ,9)

colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys)))

for y, line_length, color, ax in zip(ys, line_lengths, colors, axes.flat):
    ax.hlines(y=y, xmin=1, xmax=line_length, colors=color)
```

Edit: using [tmdavison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63482999/11751294)'s solution with `zip` is definitely a cleaner solution than nested for loops, so I decided to edit the answer.
[image: 1]

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for! Do you know how can I assign colors as well, based on the random array.
Thank you!

Comment: `j` is really a cryptic variable name. How about `fig, axes = ...` then `for i, ax in enumerate(axes):`?

Comment: @Guimoute Yes, sure, I'll rewrite variable names.

Comment: @tmdavison I just realized that it's just better :) Should I delete it?

Comment: I mean, I don't really care for something small like this, but its good practice when you copy someone else's code to at least give them the credit

Comment: @tmdavison I edited the post to include it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the axes instances and call `hlines` from each `Axes`. To assign colours, you could create a list of colours from the colormap and iterate over that too at the same time. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

colours = [cm.viridis(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 9)]

randnums = np.random.randint(0, 10, 9)

y = np.random.randint(1, 10, 9)
print(randnums)

for yy, num, col, ax in zip(y, randnums, colours, axes.flat):

    ax.hlines(y=yy, xmin=1, xmax=num, color=col)

axes[0, 0].set_xlim(0, 10)
axes[0, 0].set_ylim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]